# Aplicar opacidade somente a imagem utilziada como background e nao ao texto quando faço um hover sobre o bloco inteiro

Tags: html, css

Tenho um bloco container onde aploquei a ele um plano de fundo com a propriedade background image, e dentro dele tenho outro block com titulo e paragrafos, queria saber como consigo ao fazer um hover sobre o container mudar somente a opacidade da imagem de fundo e os textos permanecerem em destaque.

Ex:

```
<section class="cover">
      <div class="group">
        <h4 class="group__title">Visite-Nos</h4>
        <h5 class="group__subtitle">O ano todo</h5>
        <nav class="frame">
          <p class="frame__paragraph">Comprar bilhetes</p>
        </nav>
      </div>
      
    </section>


CSS:
.cover {
```

width: 92.5%;
height: 740px;
margin-top: 92px;
background-image: url(../../images/__background.png);
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

aprendendo html e css

Answer (score -2):

Se entendi bem a pergunta, você deverá dividir essa div em duas. Uma com o background e outra com o texto. E no css do background escrever o seguinte código:

```
body{ background-image: url('bg.jpg'); }
img { opacity : 0.5; }
```

Para alterar a opacidade de um elemento, basta atribuir um valor entre 0 e 1 à propriedade, opacity.
Opacidade foi alterada para 50% (0.5), ou seja, ela está com 50% de transparência.